# A good django search app? — How to perform fuzzy search with Haystack?

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack, fuzzy-search

I'm using django-haystack at the moment 
with apache-solr as the backend.

Problem is I cannot get the app to perform the search functionality I'm looking for

1. Searching for sub-parts in a word

   > eg. Searching for "buntu" does not give me "ubuntu"
2. Searching for similar words

   > eg. Searching for "ubantu" would give "ubuntu"

---

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really about how you pass the query back to Haystack (and therefore to Solr). You can do a 'fuzzy' search in Solr/Lucene by using a `~` after the word:

```
ubuntu~
```

would return both `buntu` and `ubantu`. See the [Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy#20Searches) on this.

How you pass this through via Haystack depends on how you're using it at the moment. Assuming you're using the default SearchForm, the best thing would be to either override the form's `clean_q` method to add the tilde on the end of every word in the search results, or override the `search` method to do the same thing there before passing it to the SearchQuerySet.

Comment: It now works for both Lucene and Solr. The two projects were merged and now have a common code base.